# FTP error 425 Can't open data connection

Tags: ftp, filezilla

Here is my setup:

- windows 7
- filezilla server installed on my local PC
- filezilla client installed on my local PC
- firewall disabled (just during the test)

Server and Client seems to work fine (I can connect and browse files with the client as expected).

I try to run the following commands

```
PASV
RETR /fileSource.txt
```

(`/fileSource.txt` exists on the server)

Here is the output (server side)

```
(000038)18/03/2013 12:56:34 - andro (127.0.0.1)> PASV
(000038)18/03/2013 12:56:34 - andro (127.0.0.1)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,231,249)
(000038)18/03/2013 12:56:39 - andro (127.0.0.1)> RETR /fileSource.txt
(000038)18/03/2013 12:56:44 - andro (127.0.0.1)> 425 Can't open data connection.
```

So my problem if of course this error `425 Can't open data connection`

Googling around leads me to disabling firewall (to be sure it wasn't the cause) without success.

Other common issue related is ACTIVE/PASSIVE mode. As far as I understand: `PASV` will tell the server to switch to passive mode. (note that if I don't run `PASV`, I have the following error : `503 Bad sequence of commands`... and it seems OK since `RETR` requires the passive mode. Is it correct ?)

Any idea what can be wrong ?

**Note:** I run in exact same issue when I do those calls from my android device (on the same LAN), so I guess this is something wrong on the *server side*

Comment: I think the Firewall you think is off is not really off...

Comment: maybe... any idea how can I check that (I'm really not a windows expert)

Comment: you are already doing it; your FTP transfer opens the control channel but it cannot open the data channel. Stop the firewall next you start the FTP Server then you try the transfer...